# How to use SqlDbType in c++?

Tags: c++, sqldbtype

SqlDbType is a type used in C#.  But I need to use it in C++.  I am sorry if this is a simple question.  But I tried to google this and tried to find sample code but I did not find anything other than a statement that it exists in C++. How do I use and define the enum for SqlDbType in C++?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why would you need a .Net SqlDbType in a C++ application?

Comment: Are you trying to pass (marshal) the C# type to a C++ app/dll and need to know how to do that? The `SqlDbType` is an `enum` type in the `System.Data` namespace, so passing an `int` should suffice .. Instead, if you're using the .NET framework IN C++, then it should be available to you via the normal means (i.e. reference the proper assembly and then you can call `System::Data::SqlDbType`) .... otherwise, more data is needed for your question to be answered ..

Comment: It is complicated but I am working on a silverlight app on a Windows CE system with a 3rd party custom OS.  The main program is the OS and is written in C#.  It uses delegates to link to the DLL that is written in C++.  On the Managed side, there is already use of SqlDBType because there are Windows CE SQL calls that use this.  The data needs to be handed to the C++ DLL in this format.  Maybe I will try using an int as a substitute.